# MongoDB: Add field to documents organized in a model tree structure with parent references

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm using a model tree structure with parent references like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX",
    "title" : "Main",
    "type" : "section",
}
{
    "_id" : "eYkxs8rW3dKH5SfoE",
    "title" : "element 1",
    "order" : 1,
    "type" : "element",
    "parent" : "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX"
}
{
    "_id" : "siaRPzaTgDrfWZ7kn",
    "title" : "subelement 1",
    "order" : 1,
    "type" : "element",
    "parent" : "ASkJZSkPAj8mhb7An"
}
{
    "_id" : "DrfWZ7knsiaRPzaTg",
    "title" : "subelement 2",
    "order" : 2,
    "type" : "element",
    "parent" : "ASkJZSkPAj8mhb7An"
}
{
    "_id" : "XZF9hpW8ZqTnRdkEg",
    "title" : "element 2",
    "order" : 3,
    "type" : "element",
    "parent" : "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX"
}
{
    "_id" : "ASkJZSkPAj8mhb7An",
    "title" : "group 1",
    "type" : "group",
    "parent" : "YezvuyCowZdo2ZLgX",
    "order" : 2
}
```

But now I need the information to which 'level' an element belongs. How can I get a new field with this information to the elements?

```
eYkxs8rW3dKH5SfoE -> add field { level: 1 }
siaRPzaTgDrfWZ7kn -> add field { level: 2 }
DrfWZ7knsiaRPzaTg -> add field { level: 2 }
XZF9hpW8ZqTnRdkEg -> add field { level: 1 }
ASkJZSkPAj8mhb7An -> add field { level: 1 }
```

So I guess I have to do an each-loop for all main-elements, starting with `{ type: 'section'}`.

```
Collection.find({ type: 'section'}).each(function(doc) {
    Collection.update({ parent: doc._id }, { $set: { level: 1 }});
    // go to next subelement and increase level until there is no child
});
```

But how can I go through the tree to set all levels?

Comment: Any different with your previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35864023/one-or-multiple-queries-for-displaying-data-of-a-model-tree-structured-collectio?

Comment: Yes, I think it is the better way to improve the raw data, which is in my case the mongoDB-data... That's why there is a new question and I deleted the old one. Just see it as improved question.

Comment: KInd of inclined to agree it's the same question. One might be asking query pattern, and the other says update. But **both** basically require a technique to "walk the tree", as it were. And speaking of "walking the tree", then it would seem logical that at least one node has no "parent", so why not start there instead?

Comment: @BlakesSeven: If I start at the 'end', I have to go completley up for every single tree to count the level. I think it is much easier to do this from top to down. Then I can update multiple elements by one query.

Comment: @user3848987 Nope. "no parent" would be the "beginning" and therefore the "root" document. It's children would have it's "id" as their parent. And so on and so on.

Comment: @BlakesSeven So 'root' is in this example the first object - it doesn't have a perent field. That's what I tried in my example... How do I have to do the loop - as I don't get it working...